# "A portion of my proceeds, it goes to charity" - Is adding pronoun here to refer to the subject appropriate?

Tags: idioms

**Research:** I have been listening to lots of English, and I've noticed that sometimes English native speakers tend to add pronouns to refer to the subject of their sentence, and their real subject takes no predicate.

**My question:** Is it rather common in English, especially when there's a big gap between the subject and its predicate?

First example,

> 1. A portion of my proceeds goes to charity (ordinary version)
> 2. A portion of my proceeds, it goes to charity (the version I'm asking about)

Second example,

> 3. Centuries ago, people committed crimes, caught by those police, were thrown in prison (ordinary version).
> 4. Centuries ago, people committed crimes, caught by those police, they were thrown in prison (version I'm asking about).

Comment: Personally, I believe it's just a casual way of speaking in certain regions in US - I am non-native so can't be sure - Also, your second example looks wonky and you should check for grammar.

Comment: It sounds more like what a non-native speaker might say. But "they" in 4 is plausible in casual speech where repetition is common, although the sentence as a whole not so much. Maybe indicate the sort of speech and speakers you are interested in?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence *A portion of my proceeds, it goes to charity* is an example of dislocation, in this case left-dislocation.

*The Cambridge Dictionary of English Grammar* (p119) has this entry on *dislocation*:

> This term refers to the displacement of a syntactic constituent
> (especially the subject or object) from its normal place within the
> clause to a position at either end, and its replacement within the
> clause by a personal pronoun. For example:
>
> - That neighbour of yours, I met him at the supermarket.
> - I met him at the supermarket, that neighbour of yours.
>
> In the first example, the extraposed object is said to be
> left-dislocated; in the second it is right-dislocated. While the
> typical function of right dislocation is to clarify, that of
> left-dislocation is to topicalize an item.

Your sentences 3 and 4 are confusing, and in any case do not contain an example of left-dislocation.

*Language Log* has a good discussion of [Left-Dislocation](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=629).

Answer (score 0):

Your third and fourth items sound awkward and confused. The first and second are simpler and represent a usage familiar to me as a native speaker.

The usage seems to be a version of apposition in which the pronoun in second or later position is given subject status for the following verb.

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/apposition)
> Apposition
> When we use two noun phrases (np) next to each other in a clause, and they refer to the same person or thing, we call this apposition:
> [NP 1] The living room, [NP 2] the biggest room in the house, looks out on to a beautiful garden.
> (The living room and the biggest room in the house are the same room.)

In your usage, we might have:
[NP 1] The living room, [NP 2] the biggest room in the house, it [NP 3] looks out on to a beautiful garden.

Hence my contrived comment:
*Whoever wrote this question, whenever they wrote it and for what reason they wrote it, they should be commended. A difficult usage for me to analyse, it deserves the attention of competent grammarians please. A native speaker of English, I am familiar with this usage.*

Comment: In OP Case , I am not sure that it is Apposition. In your Apposition Examples , we can take "NP1 , which/who is NP2 , is X" , where "which/who" is elided. When NP2 is Pronoun "it/they" , then "which is it / who were they" gets weird. [ OK : "The living room , [which] [is] the biggest room , looks out" ] [ Not OK : "A Portion of my Proceeds , [which] [is] it goes to Charity" ]